# ELIMINAR DUPLICADOS DE COLUMNAS CON EL MISMO NOMBRE

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Buenas tardes tengo la siguiente consulta: Estoy intentando hacer un merge entre varios dataframes en python. Sin embargo, al momento de terminar la ejecución, observo que para aquellas variables que tienen el mismo nombre, por defecto el programa les asigna un "_", y bueno, si intento eliminar los duplicados para que solo me quede un registro se eliminan todos de manera automática. Alguien tiene idea como solucionar este problema? gracias
EJ: df1. Variable Area_x
df2.Variable Area_y
df3. Variable Area_z
dfn. Variable Area_n

Comment: Por favor agregue un ejemplo

Answer (score 0):

La cuestión es que estás intentando combinar varios dataframes, para lo cual `pandas` necesita saber qué columnas quieres utilizar como "clave" para combinar las filas.

Si ambos dataframes tienen columnas en común que no han sido incluidas como clave de la operación (del merge), lo único que pandas puede hacer es asumir que son columnas con diferente información y mantenerlas intactas en el dataframe resultante. Para evitar columnas con nombres duplicados, pandas añade el sufijo "_x", "_y" a las columnas repetidas. Por esta razón te aparecen las columnas `Variable_Area_x` y `Variable_Area_y`, puesto que no han sido incluidas en la clave del `pd.merge` y por lo tanto se mantienen intactas.

Si quieres evitar esto, tienes varias opciones, pero lo primero sería preguntarte qué es lo que quieres hacer realmente.

1. Añadir las columnas comunes como clave de la operación: esto es, si la información de las columnas que comentas es la misma en el dataframe A y en el dataframe B, no hay motivo para no añadirlas como clave en el merge. De esta forma, en el dataframe final aparecerá la columna una vez.

   ```
    keys = # tus claves de combinacion entre dataframes
    keys.append('Variable_Area')
    merged = pd.merge(A, B, on = keys)
   ```
2. Si la columna duplicada en A y B tienen distinta información y quieres preservar ambas en el dataframe combinado, es tan sencillo como cambiar el nombre de una de las dos columnas. También puedes usar el argumento `suffixes = ('_columna_de_A', 'columna_de_B')` en la llamada a `pd.merge`, de forma que el dataframe combinado tendrá esta nueva nomenclatura en las columnas duplicadas y podrás identificar de qué dataframe originalmente salió cada columna.

   ```
    merged = pd.merge(A, B, on = keys, suffixes = ('_A', '_B'))
   ```
3. Antes de llamar a `pd.merge`, eliminar las columnas duplicadas en uno de los dos dataframes. Esto sería válido si, al igual que en el punto (1), la información de ambas es la misma.

   ```
    B.drop(columns=['Variable_Area', inplace=True)
    merged = pd.merge(A, B, on = keys)
   ```
4. Eliminar las columnas después de hacer el `pd.merge`. Simplemente ejecuta

   ```
    merged = pd.merge(A, B, on = keys)
    merged.drop(columns=['Variable Area_y'], inplace=True)
    merged.rename(columns={'Variable_Area_x': 'Variable_Area'}, inplace=True)
   ```